# Dynamically finding data using regexp in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

My query for a single topic_id is :

```
SELECT * FROM `worksheets` WHERE `topic_list` RLIKE `'[\,](340)[\,]|^(340)[,]|[,](340)$')`;
```

Where `'topic_list'` is comma separated list and 340 in regexp is topic_id that should come from another Table called Topic (has two column topic_id and topic_name). In this query I am selecting all the worksheet where topic_id 340 comes anywhere in comma separated list of topic_id (i.e. topic_list).

I don't have any common column between the two tables.
What I want is topic_id in regexp i.e. 340 to be dynamic and should come from Topic table. Is there a way to do it in a single query rather than in multiple queries or feeding topic_id in regexp in programming environment in a loop ?

I tried below query but it did't worked -

```
SELECT t.topic_id, w.`worksheet_type`,w.`worksheet_action_dttm` FROM `worksheets` w , `topic` t WHERE LOCATE(t.topic_id, w.topic_list) and t.topic_id in (SELECT topic_id FROM topic)
```

Comment: this `SELECT * FROM `worksheets` WHERE `topic_list` regexp '(^|,)340(,|$)';`

Comment: My regexp is correct though if your's also correct I will use it. But the actual problem is 340 in regexp. This 340 no is topic_id that should come from topic table as I mentioned above. I am looking for the query that feed topic_id in this regexp.

Comment: If there is any other approach I'm ok with it for eg. `IN` query

Comment: you need to use join..

Answer (score 0):

Don't put multiple values in a cell.  Build a separate table for the many:many mapping.

If you must use regexps, see `RLIKE '[[:<:]]340[[:>:]]'`.